# How to avoid a specific link in Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've "created" a very small script for automatically clicking links on a specific site using TamperMonkey,

```
(function() {
'use strict';
var TargetLink = $("a:contains('Click Me')");

if (TargetLink.length)
 window.location.href = TargetLink[0].href;
})();
```

When the link I'm trying to click, looks like this  `<a href="/ID/1010101">Click Me</a>` as an example.

What I'd like for the script to do, is avoid clicking on one specific "ID" and click all the other ones.

Example, I'd like to avoid clicking the ID 1, but click on 2, 3, and 4, where 4 are the amount of total ID's.

Not sure if I explained that as well as I would like to, but hopefully it's somewhat understandable.

Comment: Do you want to open a new tab or window for each link? If you just assign to `window.location.href` you will only see the last link.

Comment: No, whenever a link is pressed using this, it ends up refreshing the page, and adds new links to press, it's actually kinda complicated, but there's this one specific link I'd like to avoid pressing at all. Or alternatively, if that specific link is available, not press anything whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to remove the elements that you don't want.

In the filter I used `split` and `slice` to extract the id from `href`, then I check if the id is in `idsBlacklist`.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var idsBlacklist = [
    "1010101"
  ];

  var query = "a:contains('Click Me')";
  var TargetLink = $(query).filter(function () {
    var id = this.href.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
    return idsBlacklist.indexOf(id) < 0;
  });
  
  var blackListed = $(query).filter(function () {
    var id = this.href.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
    return idsBlacklist.indexOf(id) >= 0;
  });

  if (!blackListed.length && TargetLink.length) {
    console.log(TargetLink[0].href);
    //window.location.href = TargetLink[0].href;
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/ID/1010101">Click Me</a>
<a href="/ID/1010102">Click Me</a>
<a href="/ID/1010103">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: This worked wonders! Thanks alot, however, a final thing if you don't mind me asking, if I wanted to make it work so that if an ID in     `idsBlacklist` appears, the script stopped clicking anything at all, how would I set that up?

Comment: If you flip the comparison in the filter from `< 0` to `>= 0`, then you will get a list with all links blacklisted. Then you can click the link if this list is empty.

Comment: @SebastianRukin I added the code to not click the link if there is a link blacklisted.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried tampering with it a bit, but it doesn't seem to work.
Still clicks regardless if the link is blacklisted or not.

Perhaps it's because the example I provided was inaccurate, the links looks more like this     `<a href="ID=1010101">Click Me</a>`